# My Rails page_cache is attaching someone else's domain to links, how can I stop this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, page-caching

Let me try to explain what the situation is as thoroughly as I can see it.

I have a Rails app using page caching for a specific part of the site. When looking through Google Analytics I noticed my own domain as a referrer which I found odd. Upon further investigation I discovered that when I go to one of those pages with my domain as the referrer, the links point to a different domain name but renders the page fine. For example:

I'm on domain.com. I go to domain.com/someones_profile, and when I hover over any links it will say anotherdomain.com/someones_profile/about. Now, if I click the link, it'll take me to anotherdomain.com/someones_profile/about yet it's my page being accessed on my server (logs verify it.)

I tested this out by taking one of my unused domain names and changing the A record to my server's IP. Then I cleared the page cache directory and visited a cacheable page using the domain I just set up, domain2.com/someones_profile, and it cached the links as domain2.com/someones_profile.

Hopefully this explanation made sense. The domain that is "infiltrating" my cache belongs to someone I don't know, and the intent doesn't seem in any way malicious, but I was wondering if Rails has any sort of built-in methods to circumvent something like this. Something like forcing page_cache links to use a specific domain rather than whatever the referrer domain is.

Any help would be appreciated, I would prefer to use built-in Rails method than to write something myself, maybe/maybe not because I'm lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I get your problem. How about you create your links in pages with xxx_path instead of xxx_url? This should cause only relative paths to be generated. No domain names will be written into the html document. I would do a search and replace through the views for _url and change them to _path.

So for example, if you have this in your view:

```
<%= link_to "View all posts", posts_url %>
```

You'd change it to:

```
<%= link_to "View all posts", posts_path %>
```

By the way, this answer assumes that you're creating your links by using routes, not by putting a URL directly into the view!

Comment: *_path will generate relative URLs in page caches? If that's the case, that will solve the problem. Let me give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the refraction gem to redirect all accesses not going to a single defined host to that single defined host. This will also increase page ranking as it removes duplicate content:

```
# config/initializers/refraction_rules.rb
Refraction.configure do |req|
  if req.host == "www.you-like-this-host.com"
    # configure other redirects here
    # eg. I'm using this to migrate URLs from the legacy application
    # to this new application (eg when migrated from PHP to Rails)
  else
    # this is not your hostname, redirect!
    req.permanent! :host => "www.you-like-this-host.com"
  end
end
```

Refraction runs early in the rack stack so it's pretty lightweight. Apache's mod_rewrite won't work reliably with passenger for example, so I prefer refraction.

Be sure to load as a middleware plugin:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.middleware.insert_before ::Rack::Lock, ::Refraction, {}
```

Links with host name should never appear in the page cache. Are you sure you generate your in-site URLs without the host name? Maybe you tried to create unique links this way (by passing the current host name to `link_to` or `url_for`), better use refraction for that and cleanup your code.

Comment: PS: Lately we found some accesses from proxies in our logs which mirror sites and insert ads and modify phone numbers. Be sure to compare the remote IPs when you watch your logs when accessing the foreign domains.